# Two objects are created after registering with Django

Tags: django, database, post, django-views, save

After registration, two objects are entered in the database, one with only the user, the other with the user and first and last name.

This is because I save twice, but when saved once will fail
`u = UserProfile(user=user, name=user_name, last_name=last_name) u.save()`

*views.py*

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user_name = form.cleaned_data['username']
            last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']

            if UserProfile.objects.filter(user__username=user_name).exists():
                messages.error(request, 'This username is already taken. Please choose a different one.')
            else:
                user.save()
                u = UserProfile(user=user, name=user_name, last_name=last_name)
                u.save()

                login(request, user)
                messages.success(request, 'Successful registration')
                return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Registration error')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'service/register.html', {'form': form})
```

*models.py*

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Name')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Last name')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'User: {self.user}'
```

*forms.py*

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label='Name', widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'autocomplete': 'off'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Last name', widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'autocomplete': 'off'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Again password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'last_name', 'password1', 'password2')
```

I tried to save with one save, but it saves without a first and last name or an error pops up `save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'user'.`

Comment: Well these are two different models, so you need to save twice, once the `User` object, and once the `UserProfile`, but IMHO, it is *very* strange why you use a `UserProfile` in the first place, since the "original" `User` model already has a `username`, `first_name` and `last_name`.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem, I need the data to be displayed in the admin

Comment: it already displays the first name/last name in the admin for the user model: `/admin/auth/user/`